# Regex works in textwrangler but something isn't right in my ruby script

Tags: ruby, regex

Could I get someone to punch holes in my script?  My regex works fine to find urls in textwrangler but when I run my script the parseducc.txt file is putting bits and pieces of things on different lines.

```
export = File.new("parseducc.txt" , "w+")
File.open("uccdata.txt").each_line do |line|

    line.scan(/(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z]){3,4}/) do |x|
        export.puts x
    end
end
```

### sample output

> dhl-usa.
>   a
>   m
>   upsfreight.
>   t
>   m
>   fedex.
>   x
>   m
>   myyellow.
>   w
>   m

My goal with this script is to scan through a file line by line and pull out the URLs and dump them one per line into a new output file.  I have tried several variations of this script but clearly I am missing something.  I'm guessing it is in my regex but I've used different variations of that which I found on regexlib.com and they displayed vary similar problems.

Comment: Could you post the contents of your input file?

Answer (score 1):

*Try this one:*

```
export = File.new("parseducc.txt" , "w+") 
File.open("uccdata.txt").each_line do |line| 
  line.scan(/(https?:\/\/\S+)/) do |x| 
    export.puts x 
  end 
end
```

Comment: That answers one question.  It is definitely my regex.  That worked fine except it keys in on the http(s):// to identify the url and I need the slashes, colons, and http stripped off to reveal just the domain name of the destination.

Comment: @LillyBean - If you want just domain name, then go with `/https?:\/\/([-a-z\d.]+)/i`